# JavaScript: base64 encode как сделать, чтобы excel распознавал числовые данные как строку, а не как число

Tags: javascript, excel, кодировка, base64

использую такую функцию:

```
DataGrid.prototype.exportToExcel = function () {
        var table = this._generateGridTable(true);       
        var uri = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,',
            template = '<html><head><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/plain; charset=UTF-8"/></head><body><table border="1" border-collapse="collapse">{table}</table></body></html>',
            base64 = function (s) { return window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(s))) },
            format = function (s, c) { return s.replace(/{(\w+)}/g, function (m, p) { return c[p]; }) };            

        var ctx = { table: table.html() }

        var link = document.createElement('a');
        link.href = uri + base64(format(template, ctx));
        link.download = this.definition.exportFilename + ".xls";
        document.body.appendChild(link); // needed for FF
        link.click();
        document.body.removeChild(link);
    }
```

все замечательно работает, но если в таблице имеется очень большое число (например телефон неправильно указан), то excel его не передает как оно есть.
Пример: в таблице указано 972544966794, но в excel это как 9.72545E+11
как с этим бороться?

Comment: Не подсовывать html-разметку excel'ю?

Comment: @Qwertiy  невозможно

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для ячейки с длинным числом нужно установить стиль `mso-number-format: '\@'`:

```
<td style="mso-number-format: '\@'">1234567890123456789</td>
```

Comment: спасибо, работает!